# Could not load file or assembly .. There is not enough space on the disk. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070070)

Tags: asp.net, exception, iis, memory

I have hosted the site in `d:/` where there is ample space but in `c:/` there is less space like around 2 mb.
I get this error below.
The server is Windows 2008 hosted on IIS 5.0, asp.net 2.0 site.

*`There is not enough space on the disk. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070070)`*

Comment: Make sure you have enough disk space everywhere. A c: drive with only 2mb free (and most likely either the temp folder or the swap file on it) will give you all sorts of problems. Fix that.

Comment: Only 2mb free on the system drive will cause issues with everything, everywhere. Time to clean up.

Comment: when we use asp.net server caching , where exactly is it stored .. RAM?

Comment: @RameezAhmedSayad: Maybe. But "RAM" just means virtual memory. In fact it can anyway be stored on the disk or some temporary file.

Comment: The ASP.NET temp folder is by default on drive C. There are other required spaces on that drive. So you must make more spaces available there

Comment: @Thanks All : Since it's a server , I really don't have lot of authorities except deployment. Will get back once IT Team does something.

Answer (score 5):

You need more space on the system drive.  .NET components live there, temporary compilation happens there (often), etc.  That's too small.  Just because your site's components are on D does not imply that all things affecting that site happen there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-uploading that dll again.